# how to remove this that i mark in screenshot

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I want to remove the 0/10 mark below the telephone field (see screenshot)

My code:

```
              Container(
                width: 334,
                height: 70,
                child: Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 1, right: 30),
                  child: IntlPhoneField(
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                      labelText: 'Phone Number',
                      border: OutlineInputBorder(
                        borderSide: BorderSide(),
                      ),
                    ),
                    initialCountryCode: 'IN',
                    onChanged: (phone) {
                      print(phone.completeNumber);
                    },
                  ),
                ),
              ),
```

[image: part of screen shot]

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you're using a normal Flutter TextFormField or equivalent,

```
counterText: '',
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have used the `TextFormField` widget. You can hide counter text by making it an empty value.

Example code:

```
TextFormField(
  decoration: const InputDecoration(
    counterText: '',
  ),
);
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are using [intl_phone_field](https://pub.dev/packages/intl_phone_field) package. The (not so good) [documentation](https://pub.dev/documentation/intl_phone_field/latest/intl_phone_field/IntlPhoneField-class.html) contains a `disableLengthCheck` property. If you set that to `true` the 0/10 is gone. like this:

```
            IntlPhoneField(
              disableLengthCheck: true,
              decoration: const InputDecoration(
                labelText: 'Phone Number',
                border: OutlineInputBorder(
                  borderSide: BorderSide(),
                ),
              ),
              initialCountryCode: 'IN',
              onChanged: (phone) {
                print(phone.completeNumber);
              },
            ),
```